# How to install GRUB to a 4 GB SD Card

Tags: grub

I tried to install Kali Linux with Windows 8.1 but I couldn't install GRUB or LILO so it says "Missing Operating System". How can I install GRUB to an SD Card?

Comment: Just an aside--SD cards have a limited number of write cycles.  They are designed for storage rather than use as a hard disk replacement.  I'm not that familiar with Kali.  Some versions of Linux just read off the drive to load everything into memory and then might write a save file at the end of the day.  SD would probably be fine for that.  But if it runs in a mode where there is constant writes, you may burn through the service life of the card.

Comment: ALso, not all systems would let you boot off an SD card

Comment: I've never used Kali Linux, but it's Debian based like Ubuntu. On Ubuntu you must have an internet connection when installing on UEFI systems, because Grub2 isn't included on the actual disc; it's downloaded during the installation process. Perhaps Kali Linux has the same issue? Did you have an internet connection (under Kali Linux) while you installed it? ( http://askubuntu.com/a/464572 , http://askubuntu.com/q/438810 )

Comment: No it wasn't connected.